# Metal multiple compute shaders vs single

Tags: ios, multithreading, opengl-es, metal, metalkit

I am running multiple (4 or 5) compute shaders that process the same data and give different outputs. User may however enable one, some, or all of them. I have two choices from performance consideration:

1. Merge all those compute shaders into one and calculate everything in a single pass. Then based on user input, selectively display the data. This needs a single pass but the number of parameters to compute shader might increase (upto 8 MTLBuffers),
2. Split them into multiple shaders and use multiple passes to compute each and every piece of data. Each pass uses a different compute command encoder.

Are multiple passes where the data already resides in GPU bad from performance perspective? Which option is recommended from performance consideration?

Comment: Have you successfully used multiple compute shaders in series? I'm trying to do this, i.e. trying passing the output of one kernel function to the input of the next, but can't get it to work. I'm using different compute command encoders, and I'm reusing the command buffer. The output of the whole pipeline appears to be empty when I do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect option 2 to perform just as well, unless there is significant overlap in the calculations performed by each shader (ie, shared temporaries.) The overhead of the command buffers is pretty negligible.

You can profile this using Instruments and the "Metal System Trace" template. It'll tell you how long each kernel spends executing and the gaps between them (where memory copy, command buffer queuing etc. happens). If the profile for option 2 shows a ton of gaps where the GPU is not being used, then I'm wrong and maybe you need to do less passes :)